# Detect header or paragraph or bold/italic inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to check if div has header or pre or paragragh tag. Similary font tags have italic or bold tags.

examples of div can be.

```
<div id="header">
<h1>
<font>
<i></i>
</font>
</h1>
</div>
```

or if div has 'p' and 'bold' tags inside the font.

```
 <div id="header">
    <p>
    <font>
    <b></b>
    </font>
    </p>
    </div>
```

How to detect which element div has . I am doing like.

```
if($('#headline header'))
{
alert("headline");
}
if($('#headline paragraph'))
{
alert("paragraph");
}
```

But this is returning both the values.

Here is my div

[image: Div]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make use of [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
var header = $("#header");

if(header.has("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").length) {
   alert("#header div has header");
}

if(header.has("p").length) {
   alert("#header div has paragraph");
}
```

Comment: thanks i tried and it says #header div has header and #header div has paragraph (returning both values)

Comment: sorry, i double checked return value of `.has()`, it's returning jQuery object, so you'll need call `.length` to check its existance.

Comment: my code is using `#header`, your HTML is using `#headline`.
please update your code accordingly.

Comment: yes now working fine and how to detect if <i> or <b> inside font tag

Comment: I've shown how to do `h1` to `h6` and `p`, I'm sure you can work out how to do `i` and `b`. * wink *

Comment: You can use `(":header")` pseudo instead of `("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")`

Answer (score 2):

`$('Anything that you put inside this string as a parameter for the jQuery function')` will return an object whose truthiness is `true`. Use `$('` … `').length` instead. This will return either `0` which in an `if` statement will be evaluated as `false` or any other number which is considered `true`.

Also `header` and `paragraph` are not the tag names you’re looking for. You probably meant `h1` and `p` and then again `#header` instead of `#headline`.